# Why join pruning is not there in Google-BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm new to BigQuery.
Tried one SQL(with standard SQL) in BigQuery which is basically like:

select T1.C1,T1.C2
from T1 left outer join T2
on T1.C1 = T2.C3

For other RDMS as I know, a join pruning will happen, which means the left outer join will not happen at execution time, since no result field/column is from T2 (right side of the left outer join).

However, in BigQuery, based on execution details of query history, the left outer join always happens, no matter result set contains fields from right side or not.

Could anyone suggest if BigQuery is designed like this?
Any way to avoid the join when no field selected from right side?

Thanks!

Matt

Comment: It hasn't been a commonly requested feature request. You could [submit a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187149%2B) if you want to.

Comment: Thanks for the query reply! No wonder. This will affect query performance,since a join in general is expensive. And will have more data processed (because need to read right side table), means more money charged for a client if it's not a flat rate one.

Comment: We need this feature, because views with left outer joins (generally connect fact with master data tables) will be used by different users and they shoot diff queries to a view, but only need to show fields from some master data tables, not all; means not all left outer joins should happen at run time. Will submit a feature request accordingly.

Comment: Submitted a feature request:https://issuetracker.google.com/123334463